# Removing multiple elements from array by index in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array. For example,

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I know the command

```
x.delete_at(i)
```

will delete the element at index *i* from the array. But from what I've read, it can only handle one argument.

Let's say I have a variable that stores the indexes I wish to remove from *x*. For example,

```
y = [0,2,3]
```

My question: **Is it possible to remove multiple elements from an array using another array that stores in the indexes you wish to delete at?**

In essence, something like

```
x.delete_at(y)
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `reject` with `with_index`:

```
x.reject.with_index { |e, i| y.include? i } #=> [2, 5]
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed) answers your query.  Also as a side note, do you recommend I delete this answer?

Comment: Thx for the link to thread! You use `reject` and linked question uses `delete_if`, so I think it's something new and won't say you need to delete it :) But up to you, of course :)

Comment: We should probably replace the `e` with an `_` here too, but no big deal really.